# Regex for validating an address in BASH

Tags: regex

I am trying to build a regex that fulfills these requirements

Number Street Name

Number - at least one digit, followed by an arbitrary number of additional digits Street Name - An arbitrary number of words (at least one) each beginning with a capital letter or number, followed by any number of lower and upper case letters, numbers, or periods (.).

Examples of valid strings are

"123 Milk Ln."

"15090 178th Ave"

"27 Hilltop Dr. Apt. 7"

Examples of invalid strings are

"F52 Milk Ln."

"156A Fantastic St."

"56 sample Ln."

"1838 Dykhouse Ave. "

```
             ^ extra space on the end
```

"1832 7th st."

Any help with the regex would be appreciated

I tried the following it works on regex101.com, but it is not working in BASH

```
    ^\d+ [\dA-Z](?: *[\da-zA-Z.])+$
```

I would like help with one that works in BASH

I have this given

"Turkstra, Jeffrey A.;1523 Magic Ln."

When I do

```
    cut -d';' -f2 addr1 | egrep -x '^\d+ [\dA-Z](?: *[\da-zA-Z.])+$'
```

I want it to return "1523 Magic Ln." But this gives nothing

Comment: What do you mean with `in bash`? Can you show a sample invocation? \d is pretty uncommon, maybe [:digit:] instead heals your problems, or [0-9], so [0-9A-Z] and [0-9a-zA-Z.]

Comment: I have this given
Turkstra, Jeffrey A.;1523 Magic Ln.

When I do 
cut -d';' -f2 addr1 | egrep -x '^\d+ [\dA-Z](?: *[\da-zA-Z.])+$'  

I want it to return 1523 Magic Ln.

But this gives nothing

Comment: I tired with 0-9 also but it is not working

Comment: What is addr1? A file, containing "Turkstra, Jeffrey A.;1523 Magic Ln."? The cut command already returns 1523 Magic Ln., so what is the grep expression supposed to do?

Comment: man egrep: `-x, --line-regexp` Select  only  those  matches  that  exactly  match  the  whole  line.  For a regular expression pattern, this is like parenthesizing the pattern and then surrounding it with ^ and $. You do both   but expect the pattern to extract the Street part? How could it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't seen the \d - Notation for ciphers, but [0-9] or [:digit:].

```
egrep -o '[0-9]+ [0-9A-Z][0-9A-Za-z]+( *[0-9a-zA-Z.]+)' addr1
```

yields `1523 Magic Ln.`

```
egrep -x '^\d+ [\dA-Z](?: *[\da-zA-Z.])+$'
```

From the manpage of grep I read, that -x tests the whole line for matching, not just parts of it, as if you shield your expression in `^...$` but you do both.

```
cut -d';' -f2 addr1 | egrep -x '\d+ [\dA-Z](?: *[\da-zA-Z.])+'
```

doesn't match. Nor does:

```
cut -d';' -f2 addr1 | egrep -x '[0-9]+ [0-9A-Z](?: *[0-9a-zA-Z.])+'
```

Why is this? '[0-9]+ ' matches '1523 ', '[0-9A-Z]' matches 'M', what is '(?: *[0-9a-zA-Z.])+' supposed to match? 'agic Ln.'. Can you explain the '?:' ?

Maybe it's unknown syntax for grep too?

What do we have so far:

```
cat addr1
Turkstra, Jeffrey A.;1523 Magic Ln.
"123 Milk Ln."
"15090 178th Ave"
"27 Hilltop Dr. Apt. 7"
"F52 Milk Ln."
"156A Fantastic St."
"56 sample Ln."
"1838 Dykhouse Ave. "
"1832 7th st."
```

command:

```
egrep -o '[0-9]+ [0-9A-Z][0-9A-Za-z]+( *[0-9a-zA-Z.]+)' addr1        
1523 Magic Ln.
123 Milk Ln.
15090 178th Ave
27 Hilltop Dr.
52 Milk Ln.
1838 Dykhouse Ave.
1832 7th st.
```

Ok, one of -x or the ^...$-combination should be kept in place, because we don't want F52 Milk Ln., not even partially.

Since some wise guy put in " in the test data, we need to include them as well:

```
 egrep -o -x '"[0-9]+ [0-9A-Z][0-9A-Za-z]+( *[0-9a-zA-Z.]+)"' addr1 
"123 Milk Ln."
"15090 178th Ave"
"1832 7th st."
```

The 1832-line is wrong, because... ? and we're missing Dr. Apt. 7, because I moved the + inside the parens, but we need them in and out:

```
egrep -o -x '"[0-9]+ [0-9A-Z][0-9A-Za-z]+( *[0-9a-zA-Z.]+)+"' addr1 
"123 Milk Ln."
"15090 178th Ave"
"27 Hilltop Dr. Apt. 7"
"1832 7th st."
```

Here is Hilltop Drive. 1832 7th st. would only be valid with 7th St., right?

```
 egrep -o -x '"[0-9]+ [0-9A-Z][0-9A-Za-z]+( [A-Z0-9]([0-9a-zA-Z.]*))+"' addr1
"123 Milk Ln."
"15090 178th Ave"
"27 Hilltop Dr. Apt. 7"
```

The rules for the trailing part isn't fully clear to me. Uppercase or Digits are allowed at the beginning, but not lowercase?